# public static function getVersion() : m2

Tags: magento2, setup, version, patch-data

Setup Data Patch script is executed successfully after running setup:upgrade command.
Now i want to execute same script with **public static function getVersion()**  function.

**Module version is :**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
setup_version="1.0.0" module_version="1.0.0"
```

**Script function is :**

```
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\PatchVersionInterface;

/**
 * AddCategoryAttributes Class for adding category attributes.
 *
 */
class AddCategoryAttributes implements DataPatchInterface, PatchRevertableInterface, PatchVersionInterface

    public static function getVersion()
        {
            return '2.0.0';
        }
```

After running setup:upgrade command attribute value isn't updated.

Comment: Are you try to apply higher version `2.0.0` to `setup_version` `1.0.0`?

Comment: I have tried both higher and lower version.

Comment: What is Magento version are you use? For 2.4.x you can remove `setup_version` and `module_version` at all. What is the reason to use versioned patches? Is your patch already exists in table `patch_list`?

Comment: patch is already exist in patch_list, i want to use same patch file. Magento ver. 2.4.0-p1

Comment: In this case you need to remove it from `patch_list` first. Other way it will not be processed.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding.

If you have already ran **`setup_upgrade`** before, there is a table in the database called **`patch_list`** that will be filled because patches are only executed once. You could go in the database and delete the entry and then run **`setup_upgrade`** again.

Below are Steps to run existing data patches file in Magento 2

- Step 1: Open the “patch_list” table of the website database.
- Step 2: delete the entry of your existing patch.
- Step 2: run setup:upgrade command to run your patch file.

**`THANKS.`**